# how to find the certain characters and replace with some value

Tags: jquery

I need find the index number and increase that value by one
Below is my code. In that `var newN`  result will be like `CmsQuestionaire[9].ChildQuestioner[0].AnswerId`.

I just need to find the index of `ChildQuestioner[0]` and increase that by one.

```
var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the index of `ChildQuestioner`, you can use regex and `string#replace`. Get the index of `ChildQuestioner` using regex and then using `string#replace` to update that value.

```js
var oldN = 'CmsQuestionaire[9].ChildQuestioner[0].AnswerId';
var suffix = +oldN.match(/(\d+)/g)[1];
var t = 0;
var newN = oldN.replace(/(\d+)/g, function(match){
 t++;
 return (t==2) ? +match + 1 : match;
}); 
console.log(newN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-apply the value back to the attribute.

```
$(this).attr('name', newN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex(regular expressions) to do the same.
Example: 
If you want replace space with # key you can go with the below.

```
var replacedString = yourString.replace(/\ /g, "#");
```

/g - is to define it as global

Like the above you can specify any character instead of space.